# Is it possible to rebind jquery events after the DOM has changed by an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is being dynamically repopulated by an ajax call.

I also have a keyup event which filters the table rows based on the user input:

```
$('input#DocumentType').keyup(function () { filter rows });
```

But when I repopulate the table from an ajax call, the filter no longer works. Is there a way to circumvent this so that I am able to use the keyup event? Is it possible to rebind this every time the table rows change from the ajax call?

Here is how I am filtering:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $cellsT = $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(4)"),
    $hiddenT = $();
  $("input#DocumentType").keyup(function () {
    var search = $(this).val();
    var $to_hide = $cellsT
      .filter(function () {
        var s = $(this).text().indexOf(search) === -1;

        if (s === false) {
          foundDocuments = true;
        }
        return $(this).text().indexOf(search) === -1;
      })
      .parent();

    $hiddenT.not($to_hide.get()).show();
    $hiddenT = $to_hide.hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Look up `.on()` and the older `.delegate()` APIs on the jQuery API site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do `$('input#DocumentType').live("click",function(){});`

Also in latest version of jQuery its preferred to use `.on()` and `.off()` instead of `live()` and `die()`